# Class '\Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp' not found in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, smtp, zend-mail

I am trying to send an email via Zend Mail Transport SMTP 
I tried to browse sample codes and use it. What I have now is this code

```
     $config = array('auth' => 'login',
            'username' => 'sample@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'samplepassword',
            'port' => 587,
            'ssl' => 'tls');;

        $transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.gmail.com', $config);

        $mail = new Zend_Mail();
        $mail->setBodyHtml('Hi From Dave.');
        $mail->setFrom('noreply.networklabs@networklabs.com.ph');
        $mail->addTo('john.decena@nokia.com', 'john.decena@nokia.com');
        $mail->setSubject('Profile Activation');
        $mail->send($transport);
```

Apparently, this code gives me error

> Class 'User\Controller\Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp' not found

May I know what I'm missing? because I tried to study their codes but they didn't have that error. And what credentials did I have to use.? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you pasted some ZF1 code into ZF2.

Answer (score 0):

This really looks like a namespace problem.

I don't know which version of ZF2 you are using, but you need to add an `use` statement at the beginning of your file, something like

```
use Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp;
```

and the create the new instance with

```
$transport = new Smtp('smtp.gmail.com', $config);
```